# Redux Persist makes redux state undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, redux-persist

I installed `redux-persist` now all of my Redux states return undefined.

All the other Redux state used to work before, however once I changed to `redux-persist`, they do not work anymore and return undefined. I have 2 redux slices, one UserSlice.js and another ModalSlice.js, I only want to have persist on the UserSlice.js

Here is an example of how I use it:

```
export default function LoginModal() {
  // Modal
  const isLoginOpen = useSelector((state) => state.modal.loginModalOpen);
  const isSignupOpen = useSelector((state) => state.modal.signupModalOpen);
  const isPasswordOpen = useSelector((state) => state.modal.passwordModalOpen);


<button
  onClick={() => dispatch(openLoginModal())}
  className="btn home__cta--btn"
>
```

Here is my store.js

```js
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import userSlice from "./userSlice";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import { persistReducer, persistStore } from "redux-persist";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, userSlice);

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production",
  middleware: [thunk],
});

export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

Userslice.js:

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  email: null,
  uid: null,
  premium: false,
  type: "Basic",
  currentUser: null,
};

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setCurrentUser: (state, action) => {
      state.currentUser = action.payload;
    },
    signOutUser: (state) => {
      state.email = null;
      state.uid = null;
      state.premium = false;
    },
    typeOfSubIsYearly: (state) => {
      state.type = "Premium Plus";
    },
    typeOfSubIsMonthly: (state) => {
      state.type = "Premium";
    },
    setPremiumStatus: (state, action) => {
      state.premium = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const {
  setCurrentUser,
  signOutUser,
  upgradeUser,
  typeOfSubIsYearly,
  typeOfSubIsMonthly,
  setPremiumStatus,
} = userSlice.actions;

export default userSlice.reducer;`
```

And here is my app.js:

```
import "@/styles/globals.css";
import { library } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
import {
  faCrown,
  faStar,
  faStarHalf,
  faUser,
  faX,
} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { persistor, store } from "@/redux/store";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";

library.add(faCrown, faStar, faStarHalf, faUser, faX);

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code isn't including the `ModalSlice` reducer in the Redux state, so `state.modal` is undefined. If you would like to persist ***only*** the user state then you can configure the persistence a couple of ways.

1. Use a [whitelist/blacklist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#blacklist--whitelist) to exclude/include specific parts of state.

   ```js
   import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
   import userReducer from "./userSlice";
   import modalReducer from "./modalSlice";
   import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
   import { persistReducer, persistStore } from "redux-persist";
   import thunk from "redux-thunk";

   const persistConfig = {
     key: "root",
     storage,
     whitelist: ["user"], // only modal will be persisted
   };

   const rootReducer = {
     user: userReducer,
     modal: modalReducer,
   };

   const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

   export const store = configureStore({
     reducer: persistedReducer,
   });

   export const persistor = persistStore(store);
   ```
2. Persist only the user slice.

   ```js
   import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
   import userReducer from "./userSlice";
   import modalReducer from "./modalSlice";
   import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
   import { persistReducer, persistStore } from "redux-persist";
   import thunk from "redux-thunk";

   const persistConfig = {
     key: "user",
     storage,
   };

   const persistedUserReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, userReducer);

   const rootReducer = {
     user: persistedUserReducer,
     modal: modalReducer,
   };

   export const store = configureStore({
     reducer: rootReducer,
   });

   export const persistor = persistStore(store);
   ```

Comment: What about thunk? Should I replace my export const store, with the one you gave?

Comment: I tried your method, however I got error saying baseReducer is not a function for the line:
"export const store = configureStore({".

Comment: @Izk What about thunk? Are you referring to the `middleware: [thunk],` that I removed? Sure, Redux-Toolkit comes with some thunk middleware by default, so there's no need to import Thunk separately.

Comment: @Izk Tried which method, I provided two? [Passing an object of slice reducers](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configureStore#reducer) the `configureStore` *should* be able to handle that, but if it's not you can do the work manually using `combineReducers` to create the reducer function.

Comment: Yes it worked thank you